# angular 5 unit testing- getting error 'Cannot read property offsetHeight of null'

Tags: angular5, karma-jasmine

when I doing unit test on my app it shows following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of null
```

In my application I am using  below code to get the height of my div element

```
totalHeight= (document.getElementById("rcyc-page-header") as HTMLElement).offsetHeight +
                            (document.querySelector("nav.menu-wrapper.brand-nav-wrapper") as HTMLElement).offsetHeight;
```

when I print the value of variable 'totalheight' it displays correctly,then why it shows this error?